# sort linux по нескольким полям

Tags: linux, bash, сортировка

господа знатоки.
Перед мной стоит следующая задача:

Строки в файле отсортировать в порядке убывания числа запросов к доменам. Если число запросов к нескольким доменам одинаковое, отсортировать их по имени домена в алфавитном порядке.

Для сортировки я использую sort, но сколько бы ни читал, не могу понять как сделать нужную мне сортировку.

Пробовал так:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '/[0-9] | a-z\.net/{a[$15]++} END { for (k in a) print tolower(k), a[k] | "sort -rnk2,1 -k1,1"}' file
```

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '/[0-9] | a-z\.net/{a[$15]++} END { for (k in a) print tolower(k), a[k] | "sort -rnk2,1 -k1"}' file
```

Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться что я делаю не так.

Comment: Смотрите [тут](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/175119-sort-multiple-columns.html) (по поисковому запросу `unix sort by multiple columns`)

Comment: [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)